# 3 Tier help in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, architecture, 3-tier

I started a simple project in 3 Tier. Added a Windows Forms Application as presentation layer, a class library as DAL and another class library as BLL.

Now, I designed some form in Presentaion layer and tried to access the BLL Class Library. But, I dont get the namespace of the BLL Class library.

I tried `Imports BLL`, but BLL is not shown only the namespace of the presentation tier is shown.

Then I tried the same with DAL and BLL, neither of these projects were able to access other project within a solution.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added a reference to these projects/class libraries/DLLs?

Right click your project in the solution explorer, and click `Add Reference...` and point it at the appropriate things.

Comment: Ok, this helped, but I am not being able to add all the references. It says `Adding this project as reference will cause a cirular dependency`. Adding, BLL and DAL to Presentation as reference, Dal in BLL and now I cannot add reference on DAL Class Library

Comment: You don't want to add all the projects as references, only what is necessary.

Comment: E.g. your presentation layer will reference your business layer.  Your business layer will reference your data layer.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the Presentation layer project and do "Add Reference" and select "Projects" tab and then the BLL project.

You need a reference to import it.